# When calling Servlet I get a 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am trying to do an exercise about AJAX using Servlets but I'm getting a internal server error.
The program is to create a list of words and save them to a XML file.

My code is as follows:

HTML that calls save()

```
    <button onclick="save()">Save keywords</button>
```

save() method:

```
    function save(){

    var queryString = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (queryString.length > 0)
        {
            queryString += "&";
        }
        queryString += "palavra=";
        queryString += list[i];         

    }

    xmlhttp = createRequest(); //creates a XMLHttpRequest
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = foo;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "SaveXML", true);
    xmlhttp.send(queryString);

}
```

My servlet (Eclipse-generated):

```
    package br.com.gabriel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SaveXML
 */
@WebServlet(description = "pega a hora do servidor", urlPatterns = { "/SaveXML" })

public class SaveXML extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SaveXML() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String[] words = request.getParameterValues("palavra");

        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<words>");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            out.println("<word>");
            out.println(words[i]);
            out.println("</word>");
        }

        out.println("</words>");

    }

}
```

My server log:

```
    GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [br.com.gabriel.SaveXML] in context with path [/Palavras-Chave] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.gabriel.SaveXML.doPost(SaveXML.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: Look at your server logs. Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: I've edited the post and added the server logs.

Comment: is line 40 == `for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)`

Comment: Seems you aren't sending the request parameters you think you are. Open your browser's network console and check what your request contains.

Comment: yes, @ScaryWombat... This line

Comment: so check that you queryString actually contains `palavra`

Comment: POST request with query string ? Does not sound right. POST should contain data in body not in query string.

Comment: My queryString, according to the log... palavra=red&palavra=blue&palavra=green

Comment: @JunedAhsan even though I passed through .send?

Comment: With the use of a queryString I would suggest that you use a GET method.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Isn't there a limit of characters of a query string in URL (as the GET query String)?

Comment: @GabrielSotero see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Comment: Your method request.getParameterValues() must be returning null. See the API this method will return null value if no parameter is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Content-type is "text/plain"
So change the Content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "SaveXML", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
console.log(xmlhttp);
```

Comment: Thanks! It still doesn't work, but it was a important step, that I forgot, through the solution.

Answer (score 0):

is this on Tomcat 7 or 8 ?   I had a similar issue on Tomcat 7 but it worked on Tomcat 8.

Think on Tomcat  7, we need to update the web.xml to use servlet 3.0